# Ruby script end before sql query finish

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby

I run a SQL query with a ruby script that should take around 2 hours.

How I can make sure the script will exit/end only when the process of the query finish, because right now I ran the script, it pass the query to the DB, and the script immediately close while the query still running on the DB.
most of the query is commands like inserts, drop tables, create tables.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'mysql2'
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => ENV_YML['host'], :username => ENV_YML['username'], :password => ENV_YML['password'], :database => ENV_YML['dbtemp'], :flags => Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS)


client.query("
...
  ")
```

I want to run this query only after the first one finish

```
client.query("SELECT ;").each do |row|
....
end
```

Any idea how to wait for the query to finish, because I want to add another query in the same script that check the first query after it finish.

Comment: it is a big query, but is it related to sql query? because the query works, i just want my script to exit when it finish the process.

Comment: Well, the client should be waiting for the query result. Unless there's something in it that makes client not wait.

Comment: Do you by any chance have `async: true` as a parameter when you instantiate the client or run the query?

Comment: Hi @LarsHaugseth, no, what this param actually do ? thank you

Comment: I tried client = Mysql2::Client.new( :host => ENV_YML['host'], :username => ENV_YML['username'], :password => ENV_YML['password'], :database => ENV_YML['dbtemp'], :flags => Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS, :async => true ) but the client still not waiting for the query result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2):

> Multiple result sets
>
> You can also retrieve multiple result sets. For this to work you need
>   to connect with flags Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS. Multiple
>   result sets can be used with stored procedures that return more than
>   one result set, and for bundling several SQL statements into a single
>   call to client.query.
>
> ```
> client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :flags => Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS)
>
> result = client.query('...')
>
> while client.next_result
>   result = client.store_result
>   # result now contains the next result set
> end
> ```